# How to improve performance when data is scattered using filegroup - irrespective of whether using independent disks or SAN?

Tags: sql-server

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15#filegroups

> For example: Data1.ndf, Data2.ndf, and Data3.ndf, can be created on
> three disk drives, respectively, and assigned to the filegroup
> fgroup1. A table can then be created specifically on the filegroup
> fgroup1. Queries for data from the table will be spread across the
> three disks; it will improve performance. The same performance
> improvement can be accomplished by using a single file created on a
> RAID (redundant array of independent disks) stripe set.

Since file group uses proportional fill strategy the data is scattered amongst the 3 files.

Similarly when I use a SAN (RAID), and a single data file, then the table data will be scattered around the SAN disks.

In both cases the data is scattered so how can the performance be further improved?

Answer (score 0):

Disks are slow, so having more than one working simultaneously for you improves performance. SQL Server does asynchronous I/O operations (tell the OS it wants the data, and the OS gets back to that thread when the I/O is done). Having more than one disk mean you have several disks working simultaneously for you instead of only one disk.

Comment: In a SAN storage data is scattered across multiple disks. So how does performance get improved when using filegroups since each file's data will be scattered across multiple disks.

Comment: The text you quoted doesn't say it is a SAN. If it is a San, then there's no gain (which is what they hint with the last paragraph about raid).